# Nested fragment with wrong activity reference after configuration change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-support-library

I'm finally looking into the new nested fragments APIs in the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)  revision 11.

Everything It worked pretty well till I tried to use the activity reference held by the nested fragments.
After a configuration change the *childFragment* doesn't seem to get detached and re-attached to the new activity.

Basically after an orientation change my *childFragment* is in an inconsistent state from which I can't get the correct activity instance with [getActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29).

I manged to get the correct one using [getParentFragment()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getParentFragment%28%29).getActivity() and it works, but I don't think that's the right way to go.

here is the code I use to add the fragment in the *parentFragment* the first time, after that the fragment is automatically added back to the *parentFragment*:

```
        public void addChildFragment() {
            Fragment f = getFragment().getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag( FRAGMENT_CHILD_TAG );
            if (f == null) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragment().getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                f = new TrackBrowserFragment();
                f.setArguments( getFragment().getArguments() );

                ft.add( R.id.fragment_album_detail_child_fragment_layout, f , FRAGMENT_CHILD_TAG );
                ft.commit();
            }
        }
```

This inconsistent in the activity instance obviously lead to multiple problem with my fragment ( binds with services, broadcast receivers and so on ).
I'm probably doing something wrong cause I don't think that this is the correct behavior of a nested fragment.

so:

Am I doing something wrong with the code?
Is this the expected behavior of a nested fragment?

Am I missing something?
Should I detach/attach it by myself?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the error that you are seeing and also how you are calling addChildFragment()

Comment: I found wich was the problem, using setRetainInstance() in the parent fragment doesn't make the child to be deatached.

Comment: I knew you can't retain the nested fragment, but don't remember seeing anything about the parent fragment.  I wonder if this is the intended behavior.

Comment: any reason why you didn't write the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted? :)

Comment: not really... I'll do it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out wich was the problem, i was using setRetainInstance(true) in the parent fragment and that kept the child fragment to be detached.

After I Removed that line everything works as expected