# Obsolete Activity reference in child fragment after device rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have a fragment with several child fragments. I place the child fragments in the parent layout with the following code:

```
public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    var transaction = ChildFragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
    if (ChildFrag == null) {
        var childFragment = new ChildFragment ();
        transaction.Replace (Resource.Id.child_fragment_container, childFragment, ChildFragment.FragmentTag);
    }
    ... place other fragments

    transaction.Commit ();
}

ChildFragment ChildFrag {
    get {
        return ChildFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag (ChildFragment.FragmentTag) as ChildFragment;
    }
}
```

After a device rotation, I can see that the parent fragment has a reference to the newly created Activity, but child fragments still reference the old (pre-rotation) Activity instance. This becomes a problem when I try to perform any fragment transaction after a configuration change. Launching a dialog, for example, produces the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1327)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1338)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:127)
at myapp.myviews.SpinnerRow.n_onClick(Native Method)
at myapp.myviews.SpinnerRow.onClick(SpinnerRow.java:68)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What would cause the child fragment to reference an obsolete Activity?

The solution offered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464570/nested-fragment-with-wrong-activity-reference-after-configuration-change) is to simply not retain the parent fragment. I need to retain the fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is just how the Android framework works. Child fragments simply get retained wholesale through a rotation if RetainInstance is set to true on the parent fragment. The activity reference is never updated in the child fragment.

I've verified that this works the same in native Android (Java) as well as in MonoDroid.

The solution is to set `RetainInstance` to false on the parent fragment and then ensure state preservation through the rotation using `OnSaveInstancestate()`or the combination of `FragmentManager.SaveFragmentInstanceState` and Fragment.SetInitialSavedState()`

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found a simpler approach for this problem, the nested fragment keeps an obsolet reference to the previous Activity it was attached thats right, but the parent fragment don't, so the best is to call getParentFragment.getActivity() in order to reference the actual activity instead the previos one.

Comment: Yes. This also works. It can sometimes complicate a design because it requires the child fragment become aware of whether or not it is in a parent fragment.